# Encoding a list of numbers using gamma coding

Tags: information-retrieval

I'm trying to work out how to find the gamma $\gamma -code$ that encodes the postings list (12, 18, 21, 22).

Is the postings list encoded just by a list of the individual $\gamma$-codes for each integer? E.g. for 12 the gamma code is: 0001100, and so the first entry in the $\gamma$-code for the pointing list is just 0001100. Or is there another representation - am I thinking along the right lines?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that you're referring to the [Elias gamma code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elias_gamma_coding). This code is a [*prefix code*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_code), also known as a *self-terminating code*. This means that you can encode a sequence of numbers by simply concatenating the encodings of the individual numbers. Since the code is self-terminating, the concatenated encoding can be decoded into the encodings of the individual numbers.

A prefix code is a code in which no codeword is a prefix of another codeword. This allows you to decode the list as follows. Read bits until you reach a prefix of the encoding which constitutes a codeword. This encodes the first number. Remove and repeat.

Finally, let me stress that the Elias gamma code is a way of encoding numbers using a string of *bits*. When you write 0001100, you should think of it as a string of 7 bits. Eventually these bits will be decomposed into 8-bit chunks (knows as *bytes*) and stored or communicated in this way – as a string of bytes.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the help! Yes I am referring to the Elias gamma code. So the encoding of the positings list is not (0001100, 000010010, 000010101, 000010110) but it is : 0001100000010010000010101000010110. What do you mean by self-terminating? It's unclear to me how one could get back from the concatenation to the positings list from this now..

Comment: Wikipedia has an [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_code) on prefix codes. Note that the encoding cannot really be "0001100, 000010010" and so on, since you are encoding the data as *bits*, and there are only two possible bits: 0 and 1. Comma and space are not bits.